# Is gold inflation-proof or not?

Tags: inflation, gold

I feel a bit confused.

I read something on this site about gold being inflation-proof. Other people stated that it is untrue.

I feel confused why. You can print money, but you can not print gold, right?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you confused about why gold isn’t inflation-proof? If so, it would help if you could provide some context of the discussion leading up to the claim.

Comment: "I read something on this site" - Link please

Comment: Hello, so for the past 10 years, gold has averaged 4.3%. I think that beats average inflation rate. And money can be printed while gold has a finite amount on earth, right?

Comment: I might add that gold isn't necessarily any more immune to inflation than other commodities or equities. Cash is one of the few things that is highly affected by inflation. The reason being is that when cash is worth less things you can buy generally cost more.

Comment: Ironically, gold is trade in dollar ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You can print money, but you can not print gold, right?

But we *mine* gold (thereby increasing the supply), and recycle it.

The bottom line is that -- as a commodity -- the price of gold is driven by **demand**.

The three demand drivers are:

1. Industry (mostly electronics)
2. Commerce (jewelry)
3. "Investment" speculation

Sometimes speculators want more due to fear, and other times they want less, thereby driving down the price.

Comment: Yes but overall it has a finite supply, right? I still may feel unsure how this relates to inflation.

Comment: @JadeFlag it's speculated on.  There's no intrinsic value except for what industry needs.

Comment: Why does it stay so stable, other than coming down from moments of crisis? Does a dollar have intrinsic value?

Comment: @JadeFlag gold is a **hedge** against inflation because people **want** it to be.  There's no intrinsic or mathematical reason for it to be so.

Comment: There's no intrinsic or mathematical reason **for anything**.  Gold has specific qualities - fungibility, rarity, durability - that make it an ideal form of currency. It has been since the earliest days of human history.  You could say the same about the new digital currencies.  There's no utter, unbeatable, final logic why "you" "must" accept them as currencies.  Many people think they are silly crap - and many people think the same about gold.  And many people think the same about government currencies.

Comment: @Fattie there are intrinsic reasons for **lots of things**.  Why, for example, gold is yellow and not very chemically reactive.  And that rarity makes it a **bad** form of currency when there are 7 billion people and they all have to buy and sell stuff.  There just wouldn't be enough of it to go around.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @Lawrence, it isn't completely clear to me what your exact question is but I'll try to offer some thoughts which might help.

First, I'd like to clarify with my interpretation of the term "inflation proof" since I haven't found a clear definition on the internet.

I would call an asset ***inflation proof*** if it appreciates *at least* at the inflation rate. Since no one can guarantee this for any asset which is freely tradeable, I'd weaken this term to: The asset has to have at least kept up  with the  inflation rate in 9 out of 10 years.

Now let's come back to gold. Take a look at some historical gold prices and US inflation rates. For example, in ***Jan/2013*** we had a gold price of about ***$1850***, while in  ***Jan/2016*** it was about ***$1160***. In those years, US inflation was  approximately ***1.5%, 1.6%***, and ***0.1%***. So while  gold lost almost 40%, the inflation rate was positive.

According to my definition above, gold doesn't seem to be inflation proof since this isn't the only time span when this happened.

But history has proven gold to be a must have asset in crisis which might be the reason for the drop in gold's price that I described. If we look at gold's price between ***2007***, the year before Lehman Brothers went bankrupt and ***2011***, which  might be the year when things started to get better again, gold rose from approximately ***$800*** to ***$1800***.

Finally, gold doesn't pay interest or dividends so if you want to outperform inflation by having gold, you rely on growth in gold's price. On the contrary, if you own some blue-chip stocks, which pay high dividends, even if stock price remains  at the same level, you may have a chance to outperform inflation rate (but of course you might still lose, because of a drop in stock price).

Hope that helps to answer your question!

Comment: Hello, so for the past 10 years, gold has averaged 4.3%. I think that beats average inflation rate.

Comment: @JadeFlag The Dow Jones also far exceeds 4% over the last 10 years - that doesn't mean it's inflation-proof.

Comment: @pcalc note that when companies pay dividends, they lose value. It doesn't change your argument, but it still requires that companies grow to make up for the dividend they paid out.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts,

1. It's not **"inflation! proof!"**  Nothing is.  But gold rarely if ever suffers inflationary periods
2. Considering **hyperinflation**.  Gold has never suffered hyperinflation.  You could confidently say it is hyperinflationproof.  Whereas it's a commonplace in history that fiat currencies suffer hyperinflation. **So that might be what you have in mind.**
3. "We can't print gold" but we mine it.  Indeed historically, when there has been gold find somewhere, the "price has gone down" in general. (But not a lot, not like when government currencies collapse, as they often do.)  So sure, of course obviously, the scarcity of gold ("we can't print it - it is created only when neutron stars collide"<sup>*</sup> ) is the reason, sure, you're correct.  No mystery.
4. The **practical upshoot** of buying gold.  The OP will be between 20 and 50 yrs old.  OP will live for another 20-50 years.  The simple fact is, owning gold is a "decades" thing. If you're thinking of buying some gold for a year or two, just forget it. It's trivial to point to periods of 10 or 20 years when gold **consistently went up** and it's trivial to point to periods of 10 or 20 years when gold **consistently went down**.

I can ***absolutely assure*** you that if you own a lot of gold for 10 or 20 years during an up run, you'll feel terribly clever.

And I can ***absolutely assure*** you that if you own a lot of gold for 10 or 20 years ***during a down run***, you'll have made a big hole in your life. Abstract statements about hedging inflation will go by the wayside.  I really wouldn't worry either way about vague conjectures like "if inflation..."

---

<sup>*</sup> Story used to be gold was created only in certain supernovas.  Current thinking is that gold is only created when certain neutron stars collide. Go figure!

Comment: Yup. If you look at gold between 1980 and 2001, it lost a lot of purchasing power.

Comment: Sure. It's very easy to point to a decade or two when gold skyrockted; it's very easy to point to a decade or two when gold flopped.  The whole "is it inflation proof?!" idea is a distraction.  Yes, gold is "hyperinflationproof" (but - whatever).